# Xamarin: avoid lighter effect on iOS navigationBar

Tags: xamarin, uinavigationbar

In my custom NavigationRender, I need an image as background of navigation bar.

I use this line to do that:

```
    this.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage(UIImage.FromFile("myImmage"));
    this.NavigationBar.Translucent = false;
```

It works, but image appear lighter than the original one due to a blur efefct added on navigation.

Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: You can try using `this.NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage` to set the background image.

Comment: the use of both is equivalent. Same result.

Comment: What do you assign to the background image? I assume not `UIColor.FromPatternImage(UIImage.FromFile("myImmage"));` again because this will set a color instead of an image.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to show `a blur efefct added on navigation`? I can't find out  what it is?  And any other related codes?